# Open app from Any url (deep linking )

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, deep-linking

I want to implement deep linking in my iOS App. i want to open my app specific page on a link (link is changing everytime) ..  i have tried this [Link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection)

But it is in Swift and i am using objective c

if there is any helpfull link objective c , please do share. Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between Swift and Objective-C. Only the syntax is slightly different.

Comment: can you please convert the swift syntax from shared link..  that will work in objc, i am unable to convert exect code

Comment: I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do. Swift is not some bizarre thing that changes everything. It is a programming language. It uses variables, functions, conditions, etc... It should not be hard to convert.

Comment: The concept is I want to open app with a url that can be dynamic from my mail inbox. But not sure that above link will do the same I need .....
Or I need try another method ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to read this code : [here](https://github.com/vipulvpatil/deeplinking-in-ios)

except this read how this will work : http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/04/22/deeplinking-in-ios/

Comment: if url is always changing, then how you are assuming this should be redirected to that page?

Comment: i am asking the same.. that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below method and update if you were able to proceed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {
    if ([[userActivity activityType] isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb])
    {
        NSURL *webUrl = userActivity.webpageURL;
        // Extract details from url and act accordingly, like redirection to screens etc.
    }
    return YES;
}
```